# Razor and Javascript method call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this razor line, the editor shows a syntax error but it works fine in runtime.

```
<script>app.addCalendar(@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentDetailsJson), @Model.Shift.Id);</script>
```

[image: Syntax Error]

What is the correct way to write that line?

Comment: I have run across this as well.  Wrapping the razor in [] or '' usually makes it happy but that isn't always the right thing to do.  Seems like VS is confused as to if the ; is for js or razor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to write that line?

The way you wrote it. You could safely ignore the stupidity of Visual Studio's Intellisense and hope that Microsoft will improve it some day. Until that day comes, have confidence in the code you have written and stop trusting what automated tools are telling you.